# AsyncTask that uses UI in a seperate file

Tags: android

I can only access the activity GUI (`findViewById()` etc.) in an AsyncTask class if it's nested inside the activity class. This makes my code file much bigger and less readable.

Is there a workaround to this issue, or do all `AsyncTasks` that use GUI methods are generally nested inside the activity class?

Comment: Use an interface in order to do the same.....Call the interface method from onPostExecute and implement it in your Activity class............

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a callback interface. Which you can then implement in your activity. When your async task gets executed then you can send your response back to the activity and update the UI accordingly.

```
interface IWebServiceResponse{
    void onResponse(String response);
}

class MyActivity extends Activity implements IWebServiceResponse{
    // override the method
    onCreate(){
         MyAsyncTask mt = new MyAsyncTask(MyActivity.this);
    }
}

class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask{
    // your code
    IWebServiceResponse obj;
    MyAsyncTask(IWebServiceResponse obj){
        this.obj = obj;
    }
    onPostExecute(String response){
        obj.onResponse(response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a simple example to this? Not sure if I fully understand what you ment

Comment: @Pilpel I just corrected one small mistake in the code I wrote.